# How to create a timer based on the time you input on a field?

Tags: javascript, time, timer, duration

So basically, what i want to happen is when i type in for example 1:00 on the field and click submit, it will automatically fill certain fields with the time+duration.

here are links of an image for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Luz0oy3a/

[image]

My Code:

```
<form name="timeinput" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">START TIME:
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Duration</th>
        <th width="10%">Time</th>
        <th width="30%">Topic / Time</th>
        <th width="40%">Keypoints</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="duration">1 MIN</span>

        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="topic">Introduction</span>

        </td>
        <td><span class="keypoint">Agenda, complete patient workflow, questions.</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="duration">4 MIN</span>

        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="topic">Basic </span>

        </td>
        <td><span class="subtopic"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Could you share a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: or could you share your code with us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Luz0oy3a/ @IanPennebaker

Answer (score 0):

Since no code was provided in the question, here's a pseudo-code answer:

```
function submitClick(){
  output1.value = inputField.value + 1 minute;
  output2.value = inputField.value + 5 minutes;
  output3.value = inputField.value + 45 minutes;
}
```